# Find Coincidence in a column of names with python

Tags: python

I have a column with names.

I would like to find similar names like this examples:

John F. Kennedy or John Fitzgerald Kennedy

I tried this code:

```
df2[df2['nombre'].duplicated() == True]
```

Brings the exact value duplicated, but i need to find any coincidence with the frist name.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is a bit broad, as it's not clear what you consider a coincidence of two names. Are you specifically looking to only match first and last names, or are you also concerned about nicknames? (Jonathon Kennedy vs John Kennedy for example). For the second case, you might look into the Jellyfish library, as it has many useful string distance metrics

Comment: Thank you G. Anderson, i´ll take a look the Jellyfish